# Do I need to apply for two separate visas for Australia and New Zealand?

Tags: visas, australia, new-zealand

I will be in Australia for 3 days before I fly to New Zealand.  Do I need a tourist visa for both countries?

Answer (score 14):

They are 2 different countries and what visa you require for each all depends on what country you are from.

[**New Zealand**](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/visit/visitors/)

If you are from a 'visa-waiver country' you don't need to apply for a visa beforehand. You simply turn up with proof of onward travel and proof that you have enough funds to maintain your trip in NZ. You will be issued a visa on arrival.

The list of visa-waiver countries is here: http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/visafreecountries.htm

If you are not from one of these countries you will have to apply for a NZ tourist visa

[**Australia**](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/tourist/visa-options.htm)

Australia has a number of options. The easiest are online electronic visas.

You can either apply for an [ETA](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETA/etas.jsp), or an [eVisitor](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CGgQFjAD&url=https://www.ecom.immi.gov.au/visas/app/uu?form=TV&ei=05WJUY3mCeO3iQeprgE&usg=AFQjCNHDQrkq9VrbUFCB1TSDwjsDhPy7UQ&sig2=jFu9znedh4s-RGJMqDvnAw&bvm=bv.46226182,d.aGc&cad=rja) visa. eVisitor is a new type of visa and is open to more countries and is free.

Here is a list for the eVisitor visa: http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/tourist/evisitor/eligibility.htm

The list for an ETA is:

- Brunei Darussalam
- Canada
- Hong Kong
- Japan
- Malaysia
- Singapore
- Korea, Rep of (South)
- United States

If you are not eligible in either list, then you will have to apply for one

All of these visas allow stays of up to 3 months. The Aussie e-visas are usually valid for 1 year, and for multiple entry.

Good luck.

Comment: But Australia and New Zealand are only 1,300km apart - are you sure they're different countries?

Comment: I'm sure. But since I often get asked how the weather is in Australia... I figure it's best to clarify.

Comment: @hippietrail did you really ask that question? I mean - were you being sarcastic?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Quite sarcastic indeed.

Comment: Isn't New Zealand an island in the GBR?

Answer (score 6):

It will certainly depend on where you're from as to whether you need a visa - some countries don't need visas to visit either.

However, assuming you need visas, then yes, you need two separate visas. They are not the same country, and while there are some reciprocal agreements for some citizens (I'm a NZer and can work visa-free in Australia), for foreigners you'll definitely consider them separate.  Different governments, different currencies, different sports teams, very different countries, even if some people struggle to tell the accents apart :)

[Find out whether you need a visa for New Zealand](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/visit/)

[Find out whether you need a visa for Australia](http://www.immi.gov.au/visitors/tourist/)

Fun fact: even New Zealanders need a visa for Australia if they arrive by sea - due to a legacy law.

Comment: wow, so if you're a NZ and take a cruise ship to Sydney, you need a visa if you want to get off the boat? Random.

Comment: @GrahamChiu bear in mind this was a few years ago, and also many countries have laws to cater for cruise ships - eg the 3 day on arrival visa in St Petersburg, Russia that doesn't require an invite like a regular tourist visa.  I only know one NZer who turned up in Aus by boat (she cycled from London to NZ) and was required to get a visa under this rule :/

Comment: @MarkMayo That sounds like it would be an interesting read. You don't happen to have a link do you?

Comment: @MarkMayo how on earth one does bike to New Zealand, is this some sort of water bike? I mean, sure, it's possible, Kon Tiki happened but you must be really determined to pedal a water bike that long.